# What should I use instead of cl::KernelFunctor?

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm following some tutorials on OpenCL and they mention a type called `cl::KernelFunctor`. However, that type isn't found and when I looked at the headers of the AMD APP SDK, I saw that the declaration of the `cl::KernelFunctor` class is commented out.

What am I supposed to use in place of this code to run a kernel?

```
//run the kernel
cl::KernelFunctor simple_add(cl::Kernel(program, "simple_add"), queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NullRange);
simple_add(buffer_A, buffer_B, buffer_C);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
cl::Kernel simple_add(program, "simple_add");
simple_add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
simple_add.setArg(1, buffer_B);
simple_add.setArg(2, buffer_C);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(simple_add,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
queue.finish();
```

Answer (score 5):

You are probably following [this tutorial](http://simpleopencl.blogspot.com/2013/06/tutorial-simple-start-with-opencl-and-c.html) just as I do. I figured out based on [this](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/8317-cl-hpp-KernelFunctor-gone-replaced-with-KernelFunctorGlobal), that files CL/cl.hpp for OpenCL 1.1 and CL/cl.hpp for OpenCL 1.2 differ in that cl::KernelFunctor is removed in the later.

The solution is to use the function cl::make_kernel that takes as template arguments types of your functor. In that particular case the template parameter is thus cl::Buffer. The code that compiles for me using OpenCL 1.2 header is:

```
cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer> simple_add(cl::Kernel(program, "simple_add"));
cl::EnqueueArgs eargs(queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NullRange);
simple_add(eargs, buffer_A, buffer_B, buffer_C).wait();
```

Comment: This is now under `cl::compatibility`.

Answer (score 4):

As @Michael Dorner said, you can replace the code by a step by step approach. Create the kernel, set the args, and then queue it.

---

The KernelFunctor is to funct-ify the kernel code so you can call it as a function. Since usually that is not the case, is rarely used in real applications, but it may be useful for some cases.

With this code you are saying:

```
cl::KernelFunctor simple_add(cl::Kernel(program, "simple_add"), queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NullRange);
```

- Create a functor of kernel "simple_add".
- Launching in the queue "queue"
- With these NDRanges.

Then when you call the functor you pass the only remaining things, the arguments:

```
simple_add(buffer_A, buffer_B, buffer_C);
```

The good thing is that you can later on launch it with different arguments in an easy way, by just:

```
simple_add(buffer_B, buffer_C, buffer_D);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cl::KernelFunctor<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer> simple_add(program, simple_add);
cl::EnqueueArgs eargs(queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NullRange);
// call func
simple_add(eargs, buffer_A, buffer_B, buffer_C);
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Redefinition of `simple_add` in the first line. Even with changed name `No matching constructor for initialization of 'cl::KernelFunctor<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>' [ovl_no_viable_function_in_init]`. Does not work.